# Pymongo query with $lte and $gte not working

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I have the following document in mongo:

```
{
    'Name': 'Dummy',
    'North-East-Bound': {
        'lat': 0,
        'lng': 0
    },
    'South-West-Bound': {
        'lat': 0,
        'lng': 0
    }
}
```

I'm doing the following query:

```
result = self.coll.find_one({
            'North-East-Bound':
                {'lat': {'$gte': lat},
                 'lng': {'$gte': lng}
                 },
            'South-West-Bound':
                {'lat': {'$lte': lat},
                 'lng': {'$lte': lng}
                 }
        })
```

Obviously I'm using lat=0 and lng=0 as parameters. I want the dummy document to be returned, but I just get None. What have I done wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to use dot notation to run queries on the field for embedded document.

```
 find_one({
      'North-East-Bound.lat': {
          '$gte': lat
      },
      'North-East-Bound.lng': {
          '$gte': lng
      },
      'South-West-Bound.lat': {
          '$lte': lat
      },
      'South-West-Bound.lng': {
          '$lte': lng
      }
  })
```

This will work for equality comparison. This is embedded document level comparison.

```
find_one({
    'North-East-Bound': {
        'lat': 0,
        'lng': 0
    },
    'South-West-Bound': {
        'lat': 0,
        'lng': 0
    }
})
```

More here

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field